# Drillup Button Click Listener - Vaadin Charts

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I know that drillup button works on the client side, but is there any way to know when that button is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [ColumnWithLazyMultiLevelDrilldown](https://github.com/vaadin/charts/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/com/vaadin/addon/charts/examples/columnandbar/ColumnWithLazyMultiLevelDrilldown.java) class you can see example of using ChartDrillupListener.

```
Chart chart = new Chart(ChartType.COLUMN);

chart.addChartDrillupListener(new ChartDrillupListener() {

  @Override
  public void onDrillup(ChartDrillupEvent event) {
      log("ChartDrillupEvent");
  }
});
```